# Error when starting Wildfly 9

Tags: configuration, wildfly

I am getting the below error when starting Wildfly 9 from eclipse.

```
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
Unable to set property pattern on class org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(PropertyConfigurator.java:187)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureFormatter(PropertyConfigurator.java:360)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:305)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:86)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:470)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered an unknown format character
    at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.FormatStringParser.getSteps(FormatStringParser.java:168)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter.setPattern(PatternFormatter.java:63)
    ... 21 more
Declared property enabled wasn't found on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
```

This is the entry for the same in the standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb.config">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

Is there something wrong in the configuration or is there anything additional that needs to be added to fix the issue?

Comment: This error doesn't look like it came from WIldfly 9. are you sure eclipse isn't launching as7?

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse(mars). I haven't configured the as7 with this version of eclipse. Is there some way i can confirm?

Comment: Tough to tell. You could delete the logging subsystem from wf9 and then as7 to see if it has any effect. I only say this because the error line number in your stack trace is from logging 1.2. Wf9 ships with 2.0.

Comment: It looks like maybe there's an older version `jboss-logmanager` getting loaded. The correct version of WildFly should be launching otherwise you'd see an issue with the namespace. Well I guess assuming it got that far :)

Anyway this is definitely an environmental issue. Make sure you have the correct version of WildFly installed and no other `jboss-logmanager` can be found on the boot class path.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the jboss-logmanager was of older version. It wasnt compatible with WildFly 9. Once i changed it to the one that is compatible with the WildFly 9. Its working. Thanks @JamesR.Perkins.